# Android Video streaming using HLS

Tags: android, android-video-player, android-videoview

I am assigned with a task to play a video in Android. Also, they mentioned if I use HLS it would be nicer. I tried playing video in VideoView, works good. I don't know anything about HLS. So I request, if I get some valuable resources on how to play video using HLS in android, it would be great.

Any leads are appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Android `VideoView` has limited steaming support (HLS, DASH, Smooth Stream, etc.) especially on older API versions.  The best option would be to use the [ExoPlayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer) library from google (or a wrapper around it like [ExoMedia](https://github.com/brianwernick/ExoMedia)).

As an note, the streaming protocols are only supported on API 15+